# Unit Testing in UWP application throws COMException

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Here is the setup I used to reproduce my issue:

1. Create a UWP Library with the one call as follows:

   ```
   using namespace Windows::UI::ViewManagement;
   void noop() {
     auto bounds = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView()->VisibleBounds;
   }
   ```

   This function uses the ApplicationView to get the screen bounds of the current app instance.
2. Create another UWP Test App which references the library. Within it's test method, I call the noop() from MyLib.

On running the tests, it fails and throws a Platform::COMException^. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call the `noop()` on the UI thread since you are dealing with some UI elements.

You can use `[UITestMethod]` instead of `[TestMethod]` in top of your test method implementation.